# c# User.IsInRole Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Note, I am using c# MVC 3, I am trying to use this within a class, NOT a controller.

I have the following at top of my program

```
    using System.Web.Security;
```

I tried to do the following but get the message:

*The name 'User' does not exist in the current context.*

Here is my partial code:

```
     using System.Web.Security;
     ....
     ....

     if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))  
     {

     }
```

I am thinking that is has to do something with the namespace but looking at the documentation, all I should need is System.Web.Security.

Comment: `User` is part of the context or `Page`, where are you trying to access `User`?

Comment: Sorry, is this an MVC  web project?  If so add `using System.Web.Mvc;`

Comment: are you using asp.net web project or asp.net mvc ?

Comment: Where is this code? Inside a Controller method? Inside a class?

Comment: @Forty-Two, Thanks, I am using MVC. I tried to do using System.Web.Mvc but my pogram didn't recognize it. I believe I need a reference. Where do I find the reference at?

Comment: Get yourself a copy of ReSharper - it'll prompt you to add missing using statements automatically (amongst a great many other things)

Comment: See [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx). But if a reference does not already exist, then I doubt this will fix your problem.

Comment: @levelnis - I am using MVC, this is in a class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Try first :** while executing the view, check the following in controller `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin")`  - this line check your value.

It should return a `bool` value if you have current HttpContext loaded.

**Solution #2:**  Look at the default mvc3 project:

```
Context.User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

instead of `Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")`.

**In addition**: you may check this post about how to set usage of roles - [User.IsInRole(" ") without using Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2282260/1437962).

Look for the following usage **with** `ASP.NET MVC Membership` classes :

- [Membership and Authorization in ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/membership-and-authorization-in-Asp-Net-mvc-3-razor/)
- [SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)
- [Asp.net membership - how to determine programmatically is user is in role](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1213964/1437962)
- [ASP.NET MVC Membership Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9016091/1437962)

Comment: Thanks. I do not see Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"). Note that I am using MVC and this code is not a controller but a class file. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You would need to use `Membership` in order to be able to do Role checks in class.

Comment: Where can I find out more on Membership.

Comment: i have provided references in my answer, check them

Answer (score 4):

add `using System.Web.Mvc;`
That should do it

So based on your comment, I'm going to assume you are working in a class that is not a Controller, but is inside your MVC project.  So you should be able to do what you are attempting like so

```
if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
      //...         
    }
```

Comment: Right click `references` in solution explorer and choose "add reference".  Click .NET tab and find the System.Web.Mvc component name

Comment: If you have to add a reference to System.Web.Mvc, then I don't think that you are working with a standard MVC project. Is it possible this code is in a Model layer that is a code library?

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - I am using MVC but this code is inside of a class. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: @Forty-Two - I am using MVC but this code is inside of a class. Please advise. Thank you

Comment: You say you are using MVC, but System.Web.Mvc should have been referenced by default (otherwise an MVC project wouldn't compile). Did you add a class library to your solution (perhaps as a DataTier or Model or whatchamacallit)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("yourRole")`

Hope it will help :)